# Is uniform convergence a necessary condition for interchangeability of limits

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am aware of the [standard result](https://github.com/ProFatXuanAll/terence-tao-analysis/blob/master/Analysis-II/3-3-uniform-convergence-and-continuity.tex) (namely, please see Terence Tao's *Analysis II, Page 54, Proposition 3.3.3 - Interchange of limits & uniform limits*) that uniform convergence implies the interchangeability of limits, however I am wondering if the converse holds.

i.e. If we can interchange the limits of a function, does it imply the uniform convergence of this function please?

I don’t think it holds but I am struggling to construct a counterexample.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the frontal statement of the theorem you want a counterexample of?

Comment: Hi I am not sure if there is such a theorem. I am just considering the converse of proposition that uniform convergence implies limit interchangeablity. In the converse case, I am not specifying what the limit interchanging operation might be, it could be commuting summations with integrals, or commuting differential operators with integrals (e.g. Leibniz integral rule). Hope it helps :) @SassatelliGiulio

Comment: Can you edit your question with a standard online link to a paper/document or a reference to a book where the result in the first page is proved? I know you have a counterexample, but if your question gets more context, I believe that people have worked on necessary and sufficient conditions for limit exchange in the recent past, and I could try and give an answer if context was given.

Comment: Please see Terence Tao's Analysis II, Page 54, Proposition 3.3.3 (Interchange of limits & uniform limits) @SarveshRavichandranIyer

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look for a general exchangeability condition in the literature.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for something like this sequence:

$x_m=\frac{1}{m}$

And applying this to the function which doesn't uniformly converge but pointwise converges:

$ \forall x\in [0,1] : f_n(x)=x^n $

the limits are interchangeable and look something like this:

$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x_m)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(0)=0$

$ \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x_m)=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}f(x_m)=0$

When $f$ is the pointwise limit function which $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 1$ otherwise $f(1)=1$.

We actually can say more, we know the limits are interchangeable do to continuity, and continuity isn't preserved under pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thank you! I assume that we are restricting $x \in[0, 1]$ for the pointwise convergence?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, a minor mistake though - we need to restrict x to be strictly less than 1

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the following statement: If $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and a sequence of functions $f_n:U\to\mathbb R^m$ converges uniformly to $f$, and a sequence $x_m\in U$ converges to $x\in U$, then

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}f_n(x_m).$$

The converse is not true, since this theorem can be strengthened: *locally* uniform convergence of $f_n$ (meaning that for all $x\in U$ there is an open ball around $x$ such that $f_n$ restricted to that ball converges uniformly) is already sufficient to interchange limits, so full uniform convergence can't be necessary.

Comment: Thank you, in this case, if we consider my counterexample above, i.e. $x^n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (with respect to the usual metric), what is the radius of the open ball if we want local uniform convergence please?

Comment: Any ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$, where $x+\varepsilon<1$, does the trick. Though I would hazard a guess that my argument does not apply to integrals, just limits, since limits only care about local behavior, while integrals care about global behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the excellent answer above, I have constructed a similar counterexample as follows:

Consider $f_n (x) = x^n, x \in [0, 1)$, which pointwise converges to 0 but not uniformly.

But notice that we can interchange the limit and integration:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 x^n \,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n + 1}}{n + 1} \big\vert_{0}^1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n + 1} = 0
$$

And

$$
\int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n \,dx = \int_0^1 0 \,dx = 0 
$$